# parser error > .net Visual Studio 2013

Tags: .net, parsing

I've got a strange error, just happened with my live application, out of the blue.  When happening onto a particular web page.  I get the error below when attempting to load.  My research leads me to believe this is an application level problem, IIS related,  however I'm only encountering it on this one particular page.  No recent changes to this page at all.

Any ideas?

---

An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately

Source Error:

```html
Line 1:  <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="CDIPDisplayRSReport.aspx.cs" Inherits="HospitalInsightDotNet.customBenchmarks.CDIPDisplayRSReport" EnableEventValidation="true" MasterPageFile="~/site.Master" Title="Display Report" %>
Line 2:  <%@ Register assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845DCD8080CC91" namespace="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms" tagprefix="rsweb" %>
Line 3:  <asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">
```

Source File: /customBenchmarks/CDIPDisplayRSReport.aspx    Line: 1

Comment: There's no other details?

Comment: none, other than we're using .net 4.0.30319

Comment: looks as if my page simply became corrupt.  Recreated and problem solved